# MQ Explorer stops displaying most information

Tags: ibm-mq

After using MQ Explorer 7.5 on Ubuntu 12 to add JMS Connection factories and a JMS Destination it decided to stop displaying my two queues and subsidiary info as well as the new JMS information. I tried a few things to get it to work again: stopping the queue manager/restarting, rebooting etc. even reinstalling MQ Explorer without any luck.

I can do a status on the "empty" queues folder and it then shows me my two queues; each has "queue monitoring" set as off. Is this relevant? Can I set it on ?

Am I stuck with MQ Explorer to display and manage the JMS objects (there doesn't seem to be any documentation about how to use the command line for JMS objects) ?

more detail:

so I created objects using the following:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL (QUEUE_FROM)
DEFINE QLOCAL (QUEUE_TO)

SET AUTHREC PROFILE(QUEUE_FROM) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PRINCIPAL('bsmith') AUTHADD(PUT,GET)
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(QUEUE_TO) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PRINCIPAL('bsmith') AUTHADD(PUT,GET)

SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR) PRINCIPAL('bsmith') AUTHADD(CONNECT)

DEFINE CHANNEL (CHANNEL1) CHLTYPE (SVRCONN) TRPTYPE (TCP)

SET CHLAUTH(CHANNEL1) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS('127.0.0.1') MCAUSER('bsmith')

DEFINE LISTENER (LISTENER1) TRPTYPE (TCP) CONTROL (QMGR) PORT (1415)

START LISTENER (LISTENER1)
```

So these were all visible then in MQ Explorer using a user that was part of group mqm.

I then added, using MQ Explorer, a file based JMS context, two JMS Connection Factories, and a JMS Destination. After adding the JMS Destination the MQ Explorer stopped displaying everything except the Queue Manager and the JMS context in the MQ Explorer UI.

if I try to start the `LISTENER` again using  the command `START LISTENER (LISTENER1)` it will tell me that it is already started. When I add a new queue to the queue manager using a command it also is not visible on the UI. A refresh doesn't change this.

/etc/environment is set to:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45
 export MQSERVER="SWI_CHANNEL/TCP/COM22189(1415)"
 export MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH=/opt/mqm/java/lib64
 export MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH=/opt/mqm/java
 export MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH=/var/mqm
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mqm/java/lib64
 CLASSPATH=.:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar:/opt/mqm/samp/wmqjava/samples:/opt/mqm/samp/jms/samples:${JAVA_HOME}:${MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH}:${CLASSPATH}
```

PATH=".:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin:${MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH}"

trying the JMS Admin tool suggested gives :

/opt/mqm/java/bin$ ./JMSAdmin -v

> Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 5724-H72, 5655-R36, 5724-L26,
>   5655-L82 (c) Copyright IBM Corp. 2008, 2011 All Rights Reserved. US
>   Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
>   restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. Starting
>   WebSphere MQ classes for Java(tm) Message Service Administration
>
> Initializing JNDI Context...    INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY:
>   com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory    PROVIDER_URL:
>   file:/C:/JNDI-Directory JNDI initialization failed, please check your
>   JNDI settings and service. The name '"/C:/JNDI-Directory"' cannot be
>   resolved
>
> Error: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name
>   '"/C:/JNDI-Directory"

Comment: The question is not clear.  Add details and if possible screenshots.  As far restarting the mq explorer, I don't think its required.  You can just refresh the view to see the objects in the right pane.  JMS administration is possible in command line through JMSAdmin tool.  Refer to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614256.  queue monitoring has nothing to do with the view.

Comment: thanks ... more detail added

Comment: I also tried to add a new queue manager and then queues under it using a renamed version of the commands listed above and only the new queue manager is visible in the MQ Explorer UI.

Comment: I uninstalled everything and reinstalled. MQ Explorer worked for root but not for my mqm user. I added the JMS related objects and was working through debugging a JNDI/JMS program error(AMQ9509) so I went into the queue manager properties and set both the channel initiator and command server to manual. After that MQ Explorer went back to the same state described above. And the properties just set were also not available in the queue manager properties for reset. (Maybe this has nothing to do with what I'm doing and is just a spurious bug with MQ 7.5)

Answer (score 0):

The error Error: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name '"/C:/JNDI-Directory" can be resolved by creating a folder named JNDI-DIRECTORY in C drive. This is the place where .bindings file will get generated.

Comment: are you sure about that?

Comment: This issue is two years old. I no longer have the environment for testing this